# Using a bridge, an LXC container can't ping router, but the host OS can

Tags: networking, virtualbox, bridge, lxc

I've got a virtual machine running under virtualbox, and in that virtual machine I've got an LXC container I'm trying to bridge to virtualbox's NAT interface:

```
-------------      -----------      -----------      ----------      ----------
| LXC       | ---> | Host OS | ---> | Virtual | ---> | Laptop | ---> | Router |
| Container |      | Linxu   |      | Box     |      |        |      |        |
-------------      -----------      -----------      ----------      ----------
eth0 10.1.0.35     br0 <-> eth0     NAT GW:          192.168.1.33    GW:
gw 10.1.0.2        br0 10.1.0.5      10.1.0.2/16                      192.168.1.1
                   gw 10.1.0.2

Ping 10.1.0.2      ping 10.1.0.2
 FAIL               OK
```

I cannot ping from the LXC container to the virtualbox gateway, but I can from the Host OS.

Note: running `tcpdump` on the host OS, I can sing pings being sent from the container to the router, and the reply from the router to the container, but `tcpdump` on the container shows no traffic.

**LXC eth0**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:ed:82:b8
          inet addr:10.1.0.35  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:3eff:feed:82b8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:585 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:588 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:58003 (58.0 KB)  TX bytes:56447 (56.4 KB)
```

**Host OS:**

```
root@ubuntuserver:/# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ca:5f:7a
          inet addr:10.1.0.5  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:feca:5f7a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2012 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:158794 (158.7 KB)  TX bytes:139083 (139.0 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:ca:5f:7a
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2968 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2404 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:281188 (281.1 KB)  TX bytes:312109 (312.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14376 (14.3 KB)  TX bytes:14376 (14.3 KB)

vethStvXMU Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:9a:36:3a:84:1c
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc9a:36ff:fe3a:841c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:557 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:554 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:53465 (53.4 KB)  TX bytes:55003 (55.0 KB)


root@ubuntuserver:/# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.080027ca5f7a       no              eth0
                                                        vethStvXMU
```

Comment: What does cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward say?
Can you ping the local ip's of your containers from the host?

Comment: It was disabled, but I enabled it previously. But in this case, we're not forwarding packets I don't think. We're physically bridging the LXC interface and eth0, so I think forwarding isn't required.

Comment: Are the nameservers configured in /etc/resolv.conf ?

If not, this might work:

cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original > /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail


/etc/init.d/resolvconf restart

Comment: It's a good though, but they are, and I'm just trying to ping the gateway by IP: 10.1.0.2. Interestingly if I run tcpdump ICMP on the host I can see the gateway receive the ping and reply, but it never makes it to the LXC container

Comment: Please don't post answers that merely ask for more information. That's what comemnts are for.

Comment: I think this answers your question:
[lxc vm access outside the host](http://serverfault.com/questions/473438/lxc-vm-access-outside-the-host/473442#473442)

Comment: the bridge code can call iptables if [br_netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is loaded (usually by using iptables' physdev match). Then iptables is used *both* for firewalling as a router and as a bridge. Details there: [7. Two possible ways for frames/packets to pass through the iptables PREROUTING, FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following iptables rules:

```bsh
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j SNAT --to-source 148.251.79.108
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```